# Delete mark ' (single quote)

Tags: vim, quote

I'm trying to delete the mark `'` (single quote) but I dont know how.
I'm doing `delm \'` but it doesn't work. I also tried every combination I could think of.

I realize this is more a Vim script question, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to delete that mark? It's an **automatic one** (excerpt from [`:he ''`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27%27)):

> ''  ``      To the position before the latest jump, or where the
>               last "m'" or "[m`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#m%60)" command was given.  Not set when the
>               |[:keepjumps](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:keepjumps)| command modifier was used.
>               Also see |[restore-position](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#restore-position)|.

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't know `` was the same as ''. I was deleting all the marks I didn't use. Thank you :)

Comment: those two aren't exactly the same; '' goes to the beginning of the line and `` goes to the point in the line where you were when you left it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand the question, are you talking about markers (`:help mark`)? If so, `'` is not a valid marker, vim only supports `m{a-zA-Z}` Well, `'` *is* a marker but not a one you can delete/change.

`'` has special meaning in vim (`:help ''`):

```
''  ``          To the position before the latest jump, or where the
            last "m'" or "m`" command was given.
```